# Why Is my Code not working (RBLXWILD Autojoiner)

Tags: helper

I have a Autojoiner for cases in RBLXWILd it worked and all but like since 2 Weeks it opens you can make the settings and then there comes a error or smth and it closes

Making a RBLXWILD Case joiner and It just closes IDK why

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.